# Difference between try catch and @ExceptionHandler in Spring REST

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I was going through a video tutorial where the instructor focussed on handling any Runtime exceptions through the @ExceptionHandler in Spring.

What is the difference between the approach of handling it via try catch or via @ExceptionHandler?Which is the better approach and when to use either of them?

Answer (score 1):

bro we use @ExceptionHandler above a method which we want to handle all the exception that occurs in your code while in case of try and catch you just handle the exception where it occurs only. But if we want that every exception that occurs in our program to be handled by one method, so that it will look clean and professional, we use @ExceptionHandler. Here is the link that might help you understand this.
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-exceptionhandler-annotation/

Let me know if this helps.